# How to column stack arrays ignoring nan in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, nan

I have data of the form in a text file.

**Text file entry**

```
#x  y   z
1   1   1
2   4   
3   9   
4   16  
5   25  
6   36  
7   49  
8   64  512
9   81  729
10  100 1000
11  121 
12  144 1728
13  169 
14  196 
15  225 
16  256 4096
17  289 
18  324 
19  361 6859
20  400 
21  441 9261
22  484 
23  529 12167
24  576 
25  625
```

Some of the entries in the third column are empty. I am trying to create an array of x (column 1) and z (column 3) ignoring nan. Let the array be B. The contents of B should be:

```
1   1
8   512
9   729
10  1000
12  1728
16  4096
19  6859
21  9261
23  12167
```

I tried doing this using the code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.genfromtxt('data.dat', comments='#', delimiter='\t')
B = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if ~ np.isnan(A[i, 2]):
        B =  np.append(B, np.column_stack((A[i, 0], A[i, 2])))
print B.shape
```

This does not work. It creates a column vector. How can this be done in Python?

Comment: If you would deal with data analysis, `Pandas` will make life easier with `pd.read_table(file).dropna()` here `pd.read_table(file)` read the file and `dropna()` drops `NA` rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas` would make your life quite easier (note the regular expression to define `delimiter`):

```
from pandas import read_csv

data = read_csv('data.dat', delimiter='\s+').values

print(data[~np.isnan(data[:, 2])][:, [0, 2]])
```

Which results in:

```
array([[  8.00000000e+00,   5.12000000e+02],
       [  9.00000000e+00,   7.29000000e+02],
       [  1.00000000e+01,   1.00000000e+03],
       [  1.20000000e+01,   1.72800000e+03],
       [  1.60000000e+01,   4.09600000e+03],
       [  1.90000000e+01,   6.85900000e+03],
       [  2.10000000e+01,   9.26100000e+03],
       [  2.30000000e+01,   1.21670000e+04]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read your `data.dat` file and assign the content to a variable, say `data`:

You can iterate over the lines and split them and process only the ones that have 3 elements:

```
B=[]
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if len(line.split()) == 3:
        x,y,z = line.split()
        B.append((x,z)) # or B.append(str(x)+'\t'+str(z)+'\n')
                        # or any othr format you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Not always the functions provided by the libraries are easy to use, as you found out. The following program does it manually, and creates an array with the values from the datafile.

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    B = np.empty([0, 2], dtype = int)
    with open("data.dat") as inf:
        for line in inf:
            if line[0] == "#": continue
            l = line.split()
            if len(l) == 3:
                l = [int(d) for d in l[1:]]
                B = np.vstack((B, l))

    print B.shape
    print B

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that:

1) The `append()` function works on lists, not on arrays - at least not in the syntax you used. The easiest way to extend arrays is 'piling' rows, using `vstack` (or `hstack` for columns)

2) Specifying a delimiter in `genfromtxt()` can come to bite you. By default the delimiter is any white space, which is normally what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From your input dataframe:

```
In [33]: df.head()
Out[33]: 
   x   y   z
0  1   1   1
1  2   4 NaN
2  3   9 NaN
3  4  16 NaN
4  5  25 NaN
```

.. you can get to the output dataframe B by doing this :

```
In [34]: df.dropna().head().drop('y', axis=1)
Out[34]: 
     x     z
0    1     1
7    8   512
8    9   729
9   10  1000
11  12  1728
```